# Laravel 4: Unique Validation for Multiple Columns

Tags: validation, laravel-4, unique, multiple-columns

I know this question has been asked earlier but i did not get relevant answer.

I want to know that how can i write a rule to check uniqueness of two columns. I have tried to write a rule like:

```
public $rules = array(
    "event_id"=>"required",
    "label"=>"required|unique:tblSection,label,event_id,$this->event_id",
    "description"=>"required"
);
```

In my example i need to put validation so that one label could be unique for a single event id but may be used for other event id as well. For Example i want to achieve:

```
id   event_id    label   description
1     1          demo    testing
2     2          demo    testing
```

In the rule defined above, somehow i need to pass current selected event_id so that it could check whether the label does not exist in the database table for selected event_id but i am getting syntax error like:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"syntax error, unexpected '\"'","file":"\/var\/www\/tamvote\/app\/modules\/sections\/models\/Sections.php","line":39}}
```

**Note:** I don't want to use any package but simply checking if laravel 4 capable enough to allow to write such rules.

Answer (score 10):

The answer from Mohamed Bouallegue is correct.

In your controller for the **store** method you do:

```
Model::$rules['label'] = 'required|unique:table_name,label,NULL,event_id,event_id,' .$data['event_id'];
```

where $data is your POST data.

And for the **update** method you do:

```
$model = Model::find($id);
Model::$rules['label'] = 'required|unique:table_name,label,NULL,event_id,event_id,'.$data['event_id'].',id,id'.$model->id;
```

where $data is your PUT/PATCH data, $model is the record you are editing and id is the table primary key.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try this before but I think if you get the event_Id before validating then you can do it like this:

```
'label' => 'unique:table_name,label,NULL,event_id,event_id,'.$eventId
//you should get the $eventId first
```

Comment: It generates an error "{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'","file":"\/var\/www\/tamvote\/app\/modules\/sections\/models\/Sections.php","line":40}}"

Comment: how can i get eventid first because the above statement is going to be written in $rules array that is just a public variable in the model.

Comment: if you create the rules array in your controller then you can get the event_id and concatenate it to the rules

Answer (score 2):

If you want to declare your validation rules statically you can do this as well. It's not the most efficient since it checks the database for each value.

```
protected $rules = [
    'user_id' => 'unique_multiple:memberships,user_id,group_id',
    'group_id' => 'unique_multiple:memberships,user_id,group_id',
]

/**
 * Validates that two or more fields are unique
 */
Validator::extend('unique_multiple', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    //if this is for an update then don't validate
    //todo: this might be an issue if we allow people to "update" one of the columns..but currently these are getting set on create only
    if (isset($validator->getData()['id'])) return true;

    // Get table name from first parameter
    $table = array_shift($parameters);

    // Build the query
    $query = DB::table($table);

    // Add the field conditions
    foreach ($parameters as $i => $field){
        $query->where($field, $validator->getData()[$field]);
    }

    // Validation result will be false if any rows match the combination
    return ($query->count() == 0);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [Sabrina Leggett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796437/sabrina-leggett) mentioned, you need to create your own custom validator.

```
Validator::extend('uniqueEventLabel', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $count = DB::table('table_name')->where('event_id', $value)
                                    ->where('label', $parameters[0])
                                    ->count();

    return $count === 0;
}, 'Your error message if validation fails.');
```

You can call your validator by adding the following line to your rules:

```
'event_id' => "uniqueEventLabel:".request("label")
```

If you need more fields, you could add a new where clause to the sql statement.

(Source: [edcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437704/edcs) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42116158/2056125))

Answer (score 0):

As you I was looking for hours to do that but nothing worked, I test everything ... suddenly the randomness of the doc I came across this:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
              return $query->where('account_id', 1);
           })
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique

and it works perfectly and moreover it is very flexible :)