# Laravel Validation Unique values in column for another

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I am trying to set a validation rule in my request so that `names` will be unique to `years` in `Laravel 5.2`.

So far, I have this for the request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class AwardeeRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required',
            'year'=>'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Awardee;
use App\Http\Requests;

class AwardeeController extends Controller
{
.
.
    public function store(Requests\AwardeeRequest $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'unique:awardee,name,NULL,year,year,' .$request->get('year'),
        ]);

        return redirect(route('awardees.index'));
    }

    public function update(Requests\AwardeeRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $awardee = Awardee::findOrFail($id);
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'unique:awardee,name,NULL,year,year,' .$request->get('year').',id,id,'.$awardee->id,
        ]);
        $awardee->fill($request->all())->save();

        return redirect(route('awardees.index'));
    }

}
```

I tried what was suggested here: [Laravel 4: Unique Validation for Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280466/laravel-4-unique-validation-for-multiple-columns) but it fails when I update the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was over-thinking it.

Here's the final code. I removed the validation back to the Request rules.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class AwardeeRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'year'=>'required',
            'name'=>'required|unique:awardee,name,'.$this->get('id').',year,year,' .$this->get('year'),
        ];
    }
}
```