# Unique on several fields in Laravel Requests

Tags: laravel, request

I would like to define a unique on 2 fields ( championship_id, name ) in my TeamRequest.php

But I only know how to do a unique for a field > table like that...

```
        'email' => 'required|unique:users',
```

Is it posible???

Answer (score -2):

Two field in combination should be unique in Database

You can do this in your migration file:

```
Schema::create('Table_name', function ($table) {
    // ...
    $table->unique(array('championship_id', 'name'));
});
```

Comment: yes, I can define a constraint like this, I already did it, but this is not the question. The question is about the Request Object

Comment: i think  this link will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280466/laravel-4-unique-validation-for-multiple-columns